# How are logical reads calculated?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, performance, query-analyzer

I've read the definition of logical reads from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx

it says:

"Number of pages read from the data cache."

I have two tables (Row count of table_1 is **141**, and table_2 is **16.811**), when I run those two queries, it gives the following result.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_1

results
Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0.

SELECT * FROM Table_2

results
scan count 1, logical reads 701, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0
```

if logic reads is "Number of pages read from the data cache." then what is a page ? How it is calculated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page is a minimal physical data unit `SQL Server` works with.

A page is `8K` long and may contain several table records, index records and other information.

Even if a row is `10` bytes long, the whole page needs to be read.

In your case, a page contains about `20` rows in average.

Comment: So the average of 20 rows depends on the size of rows, am I correct ? Like a very big row can fill a page ?

Comment: `@stckvrflw`: yes. If you have variable length datatypes in your table (like `VARCHAR` or `VARBINARY`), the record size will also be variable. Also, the records can be deleted, and their space is not immediately reused.